# Export each feature individually as CSV inside FeatureCollection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have a property (list type) called 'aggregLANDSAT' within 50 features.
These 50 features are added together in FeatureCollection.

```
> var coord = function(table, rowId, colId, rowProperty, colProperty){
  var rows = table.distinct(rowProperty);
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows,
    secondary: table,
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowProperty, 
      rightField: rowProperty
    })
  })
print(joined.select('matches'), 'unidos pelo mesmo ID');


var colWithMeans = joined.map(
    function(ft){
       return ft.set(
         'aggregate by date', ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(ft.get('matches'))).aggregate_array('date'));
      }

    ).map(
      function(list){
        return list.set(
         'aggregLANDSAT', ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(list.get('matches'))).aggregate_array('LANDSAT'));
      }
    );
  print(colWithMeans,'Add propertie "aggegLANDSAT" in each feature')
```

How can I export each of these features, containing the property I mentioned?
The code goes here [LINK](https://code.earthengine.google.com/66a04d3b6facb02af5c393ab4a126b92)